# How can I print input \t as tabs?

Tags: input, printing, character, substitution

I'm trying to write a program to substitute characters I input.  I want to replace
the words "is a" with two tabs, which I write as \t\t.  When I input \t\t, the output
says a literal \t\t instead of inserting two tabs.
When I un-comment out the line that says new = '\t\t' so the program inserts these characters
rather than taking them from my input the print() does the appropriate substitution.

What should I be writing so I can capture input characters and have print() interpret them rather
than writing them out literally?

```
`line = "Microsoft Word is a word processor"`
`remove = "is a"`
`new = input("new characters: ")`
`# enter \t\t`
`# new = '\t\t'`
`line = line.replace(remove, new)`
`print(line)`
```

When I tried the program I get
Microsoft Word \t\t word processor

When I uncomment out the line that lets the program insert the \t\t, it works properly:
Microsoft Word           word processor

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to ChatGPT

Add the following line:

```
new = eval('"' + new + '"')
```

before the line.replace() line so Python will evaluate the \ts, rather than print the literal values.